# Help regarding importing into LDraw

Tags: ldraw

I just have a quick question regarding importing an .obj file into LDraw. I originally put a an .obj file through Brickr and exported as an .obj. Now, I want to import into LDraw in order to visualize it better. I am just wondering if this is possible and if not if there are any solutions?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know this is quite old question, but... LDraw is not an application, but rather a digital standard for LEGO parts used by created by community. It might help to get you an answer if you specify application you are using to import your *.obj file.